# Character encoding in JSON with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, character-encoding

I want to load a JSON file from Open Data Wien [Json](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien%3aMUSEUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json) with

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "",
    success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function (key, val) {
           getJson(val);
        });
        $("#divMessage").css("display", "none");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#error").html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

but ä,ö etc are broken, i tried utf-8 etc but none works.

Any ideas to fix this problem ?

Comment: Your JSON data is encoded with `JSON.stringify`, correct?

Comment: OP's linked data is a JSON, encoded in ISO-8859-1. `Content-Encoding gzip` and `Content-Type application/json`

Comment: when i tried "alert(JSON.stringify(json));" the encoding is still broken. any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

This could be a display issue, which means JSON is probably not the problem.

Try adding those characters (ä,ö) directly in the HTML markup, if they appear 'broken' then you can probably eliminate JSON as the source of the problem.

Adding a `Content-Type` meta tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML document usually solves such problems

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Comment: my html displays ä,ö,ü,ß correctly, just in this json its broken

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a script language file you can do like this : (It's can be a few slow but if you have not issues...)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', true);

print(getUTF8("http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien%3aMUSEUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json"));

function getUTF8($url){
    //if(is_valid_url){make all checkings to avoid errors and assure that the URL is valid;
    if($read = file_get_contents($url)){
        return trim(utf8_encode($read));
    }
    else return "error";    
}
?>
```

and/or retrieve your data with this [JavaScript function from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_encode/)

Comment: Had you `console.log(myJSON);` ?